# Why is there no real coefficients in $g(x) = x - i$, yet there is in $f(x) = x^2 + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Currently, I am going through Precalculus: With Limits (Cengage Textbook), and the topic in class is conjugate pairs. The book defines a conjugate pair as this:

> "Let  be a polynomial function that has real coefficients. If $a + bi$, where $b$ is not equal to 0, is a zero of the function, then the complex conjugate $a - bi$ is also a zero of the function."

I found it odd that they conclude conjugate pairs being valid through coefficients, and perhaps this confusion is the barrier of understanding approached with the example provided in the textbook (the one of the title):

> "Be sure you see that this result (there being complex conjugates) is true only when the polynomial function has real coefficients. For example, the result applies to the function $f(x) = x^2 + 1$, but not to the function $g(x) = x - i$."

This seems to contradict logic, however: both functions have a coefficient of one for $x$. I see clearly that the former function would create conjugate pairs when solving for zero—making $(x+i)(x-i)$—and that the latter is unable to create a conjugate unless needing to use it in an algebraic step (like to simplify a side of a problem). Yet, I can not reason with how the textbook explains this through "real coefficients," which both functions have.

Simply, I can not fathom the provided explanation for the existence of conjugates. How is it true that $f(x)$ has a real coefficient, allowing conjugates to be made, yet $g(x)$ does not have one, thus making conjugate-making impossible? What exactly is meant by "real coefficients"?

Comment: $i$ is a coefficient of $x-i$.

Comment: I am confused by that...is not a coefficient the number before the variable?

Comment: A polynomial has also a constant coefficient : when you write $P(X)=a_n X^n + a_{n-1} X^{n-1} + ... + a_1 X + a_0$, the coefficients of $P$ are the numbers $a_n, a_{n-1}, ..., a_1$ *and* $a_0$.

Comment: @BigRigz $i$ can be written in terms of $x$ as $ix^0$.

Comment: So there was an implication then that I did not realize; that as a coefficient is not real, indeed. Thank you.